# Why some transactions do not show "Estimated duration" on etherscan.io?

Tags: etherscan

For example, the following transaction:
https://etherscan.io/tx/0x55208219262d9687ba18982d7c77e5052bceeada85a9075ca061d6c911778dd5

In the **Timestamp** line, you can see "Confirmed within 17 secs",
But in this transaction below:
https://etherscan.io/tx/0x93e5b8e1922705cd84b6261b3929c2ef81418fa10e0da56117d25bdccd94978e

No such information is displayed, why? is it because the confirmation of this transaction is very fast?

And when I use **Alchemy's alchemy_pendingTransactions API** to monitor all pending transactions, such transactions that do not display "Confirmed with..." cannot be obtained? Why?

Can someone explain it to me? Thank you so much

Answer (score 1):

These transactions are probably submitted to private pools (they're submitted to a single validator or a limited set of validators and arent propagated to the rest of the network before they are confirmed) in order to protect them against MEV. For an external witness (such as etherscan), they never show up in the mempool, which is why it can't tell how long they've been there.